# what are accumulation points in easy terms? and how do we use them?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've read the definition and have seen videos where they all say the same thing. We have a $\epsilon$ neighborhood around $l$ and if it contains another point, let's say set $A$, other then $l$, then we call $l$ an accumulation point of $A$. But what's the point of this? why do we need accumulation points? and is my description correct?

Comment: Given any sequence, convergent or not, if it contains a convergent subsequence whose (finite) limit is $L$, then $L$ is an accumulation point of the original sequence.

Comment: An accumulation point is a point that is infinitely close but not necessarily a member of a set or sequence.  That is to say $p$ is an accumulation point of $A$ if for any distance, no matter how small, there will be an element of $A$ (other than $p$ itself) within that distance from $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I've attempted to conceptualize the notion of an accumulation point and for simplicity let's take the metric case setting.

> **Definition:** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A point $q \in X$ is called an accumulation point of $X$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$ the set $B(q,\varepsilon) = \{y \in X \mid d(q,y) < \varepsilon\}$ contains a point $p \in X$ such that $q \neq p$.

The idea behind accumulation points is that they are arbitrarily "close" to elements of the $X$ while not necessarily being an element of the set itself. The definition is literally saying that no matter how small a neighbourhood we consider around an accumulation point, we always have at least one point of the set contained in the neighbourhood.

To make the usefulness of accumulation points more clear, it might help to think of the very related definition of an accumulation point *of a sequence.*

> **Definition:** If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in a metric space, then $x \in X$ is an accumulation point of $(x_n)$ if for every $\varepsilon >0$ the open ball $B(x,\varepsilon)$ contains all but finitely many terms of $(x_n)$.

That is to say an accumulation point of a sequence is a point where infinitely many sequence terms cluster to. The way I think of their usefulness is that if you didn't have an accumulation point, how could you even talk about a sequence $(x_n)$ *converging* to a point? If we can't get arbitrarily close to that point, i.e if we don't have this accumulation of sequence terms arbitrarily close to the point, how can we start to think about convergence?

Another perspective that you might have already encountered; if you think about general limits of functions, say $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and you want to talk about $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x)$ for this to make sense $c$ must be an accumulation point of the set $X$, because otherwise how can we even think about getting arbitrarily close to the point?

Comment: So by saying that l is a limit point of sequence xn, we are basically saying that the limit of a sequence for n going to infinity is l? is a limit of a sequence for x going to infinity always its accumulation point?

Comment: Not necessarily! A sequence can have multiple limit points, when there is only a single limit point say $\ell$, then you're interpretation is correct the sequence converges to $\ell$. There's lots of different intertwined terms and ideas here, you can even define the accumulation points of sequences *through* accumulation points of sets! The best thing to do is to carefully read the definitions and let them marinate over a few nights, use them in examples etc.

Comment: And as Damocles mentioned, it is critical that we have "For *every* epsilon neighbourhood" rather than "*an* epsilon neighbourhood" as you may have interpreted. That's really what lets the limiting process happen.

Comment: Thanks for your help )))  I'm a freshman at a university  and definitions in discrete maths are so abstract for me, they kinda make no sense XD.  Your explanations made it easier to understand! Thanks again)))

Comment: No problem, you have a lot of fun ahead of you, enjoy your studies!

Answer (score 2):

Your description is not correct. You say: "We have *an* epsilon neighborhood". The definition says: "For *every* epsilon neighborhood".

The answer to "Why do we need them" is not easily summarized here. Suffice it to say, this is one way to think about convergence, closeness, separation, and related ideas. Its value will become apparent as you continue to study topology.

Comment: Is saying that l is a limit point of a function f(x) = f(x) is continuos in l and it has  l as a limit for x going to infinity ?